# PHP $_SESSION is server side or local?

Tags: php, session

As I understand it a session is stored on the server side only. User id (or session id) for the session is stored in a cookie or url. So, a user, even if he or she is a super hacker, cannot locally change any `$_SESSION` variables that I use on my site except the session id or the user id?

Comment: Yes, the session data is on the server only.

Comment: Whether a "super hacker" can modify information on the server is another issue altogether. And, technically, you should know about [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most setups, the session's data is stored on the server and its identifier is stored in a cookie. If you haven't played around with settings or custom session handlers, this will be how it is for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll bite. Why *Usually.*?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: You could use `session_set_save_handler()` to send the data to the client. Not that you would, but it's possible.

Comment: Eh... I might say "Sessions are by default stored on the server. It is possible to configure a server to store session data as server-relevant session data on the client; however, this is not common and is not how PHP is configured to handle sessions in all but special cases."

Comment: Yeah, write a session save handler that operates on cookies. FTW ;)

Comment: @hakre - Which blurs the line between "session" and "cookie". Someone could forgo sessions altogether and just use cookies (as happened quite often years ago). I thought alex was thinking about [DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) techniques.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: That happens with Codeigniter every day by default ;) . Anyway, I don't think that the server can access localstorage in the browser.

Comment: @hakre - CI disables PHP's session handling in favor of cookie-based storage?

Comment: Thanks guy's i actually taken over site developed by someone else. Is there way to look up value of session_set_save_handler()? i does not seem to show on phpinfo()

Comment: @JohnA - You might search for and if you need to ask another question relating to "determining if my server has `session_set_save_handler()` setup".

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Exactly, their default session "helper" uses cookies.

Comment: @hakre - Yes, I [suppose that is true](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html). Any kind of reliable information explaining why Ellis Labs chose this technique over typical session storage?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Probably they love to re-invent the wheel? NIH syndrome? I mean they could have been written a session save handler for cookies but I guess they did not know that this is possible.

Comment: @hakre - And technically I don't think this counts as "replacing the `$_SESSION` handling functionality of PHP", I think this is more just an extension of how CI works.