# Is it safe to insert data to database using id from session?

Tags: php, mysql, security, session

From here: [PHP $_SESSION is server side or local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650717/php-session-is-server-side-or-local) I understand that session is server side only and client can't tinker with it.

So I assume it is a safe approach to set id from database to client session id and use it as identification to insert into database?

For example I'm doing like this right now for identification on all my page: `login.php`

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, name, password FROM user_data WHERE email_address = '$email' AND status = '1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if (password_verify($password, $row["password"])) {

                $userinfo = array();
                $userinfo['id'] = $row["id"];
                $userinfo['name'] = $row["name"];
                $_SESSION['userinfo'] = $userinfo;
                header ("Location: insert.php");    

            }
```

and on `insert.php` page

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO client_data (`data`, `id`) VALUES ('$value', ".$_SESSION['userinfo']['id'].")");
```

Comment: SQL injection... *ahoy*!

Comment: A side note: you don't select a `password` field

Comment: @esqew as we don't know the value of $value or $email, and $_SESSION['userinfo']['id'] is read from database, I don't see your point in ahoying SQL injection...

Comment: @MarcellFülöp So... you're positive that no data in the DB is going to exploit this injection hole? Prepared statements were created exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @Marcell Fülöp: it's a (bad) tradition here on stackoverflow: to mention sql injections every time one sees the variable used directly in a query without knowing how it was sanitized before. But in this case it's most likely **is** an injection :-)

Comment: Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: I fixed it now. Add the password field. Also the `id` is from the `database auto increment` so it must be secure. (right?)

Comment: @esqew Yes, it is well possible and the code sample is far from advanced use of PHP, but without knowing, I wouldn't yell about it...

Comment: are you reading the comment? look Fred-ii- also gave you the link. click on the link. To make your application more secure. Thanks

Comment: and one more think clint can tinker with it. as you set the session according to the clint info, like say you have a form, user put its detail there and than you set the session. but please read the comment. Thanks

Comment: "I understand that session is server side only and client can't tinker with it." They can if it's poorly constructed hosting, like bad shared hosting. And other potentials. The safe rule is don't store anything sensitive in sessions or cookies, instead store some kind of placeholder in the session, which is checked whenever needed. Example, setting a session to `logged_in = yes` so they're logged in, but when they want to change password (etc) they have to re-type current one first.

Comment: I try to avoid prepared statement because for me OOP is "hard to see". I try to learn answer below. Thanks.

Comment: ...time will only tell.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION['userinfo']['id']` is only as safe as you make it.
Trusting whatever is in it means trusting all the publicly accessible PHP scripts to work correctly, with no possibility to abuse them to set `$_SESSION['userinfo']['id']` to something nasty.

That's really a lot of trust.
I don't think that's affordable.
Especially when this can be done more securely using prepared statements quite easily.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO client_data (`data`, `id`) VALUES (?, ?)")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $value);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['userinfo']['id']);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($result);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Using prepared statements will also have the additional benefit of the RDBMS optimizing the queries, making repeated queries faster.

Comment: "Using prepared statements will also have the additional benefit of the RDBMS optimizing the queries" --- it's not that simple. For `INSERT` it is likely to always be slower than a raw query. Also keep in mind, that for real prepared statements (not emulated) it will be 2 DB/Network interactions instead of 1: 1. prepared statement is sent 2. data (parameters) is sent